# Тайный Санта на ru.SO

Tags: предложение

Приветствую.
Предлагаю поиграть в эту забавную забаву.
Т. к. все (большинство) находятся далеко друг от друга, можно обойтись виртуальными подарками. Да и местоположение палить нет особой нужды. Хотя жаль, конечно. Было бы больше возможностей.

Например, если Вы получили кого-то, про кого известно что он любит музыку, а у Вас есть (будет) инвайт на классный музыкальный сайт - это судьба.
Подойдите к вопросу выбора с интересом, каждому хочется чтобы от подарка на душе потеплело, а не вскипело желание убиться или убить :)

**Ценовой диапазон:** от **400** российских рублей до **600** российских рублей (цены приняты).

**TL;DR:**
Заявляемся участником; 12/15/16 получаем цели своей щедрости и ищем подарок; до 12/25/16 заявляем что готовы и отсылаем подарки; подарки находят своих владельцев; формируется публичный лог; все счастливы и, незаметно смахивая слезу, печатают "Спасибо, с Новым, 2017-ым годом!".
Или регистрируются на [сайте](http://stackoverflow.iamsanta.ru/) и там играем.

### Правила:

1. До **15 декабря 2016 г.** собираются участники:

   1. Необходимо, собственно, согласие на участие.
   2. Отослать письмо на адрес `secretsantafromru.so@sfletter.com` с темой `[СекретныйСанта:НовыйУчастник]` и телом `ВашНикНаRu.SO|Пожелания к подарку (обращайтесь как к дарителю, т. к. это Ваш Санта получит к исполнению)`.
      Просьба соблюсти формат, т. к. будет парсер.
      Пример:

      ```
      To:   secretsantafromru.so@sfletter.com
      Subj: [СекретныйСанта:НовыйУчастник]
      Body: Other|Мечтаю о альбоме "Thriller" Джексона в iTunes
      ```
2. **15 декабря 2016 г.** приём заявок окончится и произойдёт рандомный подсчёт участников и составления пар "Санта <-> Хороший мальчик".
   Санты получат свою "жертву" и его/её пожелание (если есть) и могут приступать к приготовлению подарка.
3. До **20 декабря 2016 г.** каждый участник должен отправить на вышеуказанную почту сообщение с темой `[СекретныйСанта:ПодтвержениеПодарка]` и телом:
   `1|0 (Терпит ли подарок до 25-го? Вдруг это ваучер с лимитом по времени? 1 - терпит, 0 - срочный)|Если срочно, то описание причины| 1 или 0 (1, если публичный; 0, если тайный, см. ниже)|Личное сообщение одаряемому (по желанию)|Описание подарка (по желанию)` (пожалуйста, обратите внимание что необходимо экранировать символы `|` в Ваших сообщениях, если они есть или заключить в кавычки всё послание).
   Пример:

   ```
   To:  secretsantafromru.so@sfletter.com
   Subj: [СекретныйСанта:ПодтвержениеПодарка]
   Body: 0|Ибо сроки акции к концу подходят|1|Ты хотел купить это, \|бро\|, вот вклад от меня, с Новым годом!|Персональная скидка на лигаментотомию, оплаченная дарителем
   ```

   Участники, которые не подтвердились, хотя заявились, будут опубликованы под заголовком `Плохой "Уилли" Санта`, а их цели будут снова перераспределены между друг другом, этим Сантам придётся за оставшиеся **5** дней найти подарок и подтвердиться.
   Если кто-то не успевает по каким-либо причинам, может взять эти дополнительные **5** дней, отправив сообщение с темой `[СекретныйСанта:СекундаКоординации]`.
4. Все пересылают подарки на почту выше с темой `[СекретныйСанта:Подарок]`. Тело будет обрабатывать человек, так что там без форматов (но будьте точны и грамотны :)).
   Убедитесь что Вы подтвердили подарок перед его отсылкой, иначе он может потеряться.
5. **25 декабря 2016 г.** ретранслятор по почте выше пересылает подарки своим целям с передаваемым Сантой сообщением, пример:

   ```
   To:   mailOfSOUser@mail.com
   Subj: Санта с SO на русском!
   Body: Ты хотел купить это, |бро|, вот вклад от меня, с Новым годом!
   [Подарок]
   ```
6. Чтобы не произошло конфузов вида "Я ничего не получал, это Санта зажал!", получатели должны отправить сообщение на почту Санты письмо с темой `[СекретныйСанта:ПодарокПодтверждениеПолучения]` и любым телом. Без этого подарок считается не доставленным, о чём уведомляется Санта (время на подтверждение **2** дня).
7. Публикуется список тех, кто получил подарок, если заполнена секция описания подарка, то это описание. Если автор выставил метку публичности, то его ник как дарителя.
   Пример:
   `@Other, Персональная скидка на лигаментотомию, оплаченная дарителем; Санта @Other`

Прощу прощения за то, что реализация протокола дарения проходит вручную, но... мы программисты или как? Изюминка :)

### Альтернатива:

Зайдите на [сайт Санты](http://stackoverflow.iamsanta.ru/) и зарегистрируйтесь.
Инструкции Вам вышлют на почту.

Все вопросы в комментарии или в [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Спасибо за внимание, с наступающим!

Comment: `телом ВашНикНаRu.SO|Пожелания к подарку` – ники могут совпадать, лучше использовать id.

Comment: Предполагается, что мы будем дарить только "виртуальные" подарки? А я хотел бы отправить посылку и открытку подписать, иначе это как-то скучно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да? Жесть, тогда, конечно, лучше ID. Правку понял.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, как написано во вступлении, физические подарки сложно отправлять. Пользователи не только в одной стране, нужно парится с реальной почтой (а в России это проблема), смотреть что может считаться запрещённым в стране цели (не хотелось бы отправить ручку-диктофон, а бравая таможня наряд и к получателю, и к Санте отправит). Итого: хотелось бы, но сложно. Хотя если есть конкретное желание - только за :) А открытку можно отсканировать, лучше, чем ничего.

Comment: Почему ожидается проблема с нечетным количеством участников в п.2? Зачем всех собирать в пары, замкнуть список "в кольцо" связями "Санта"-"Хороший мальчик" и все - нет проблемы

Comment: @tutankhamun, вот зачем нужны обсуждения - можно найти более удачные идеи, благодарю :)

Comment: "Зайдите на сайт Санты и зарегистрируйтесь." - Выдает Application error

Comment: "Персональная скидка на лигаментотомию, оплаченная дарителем" Лигаментотомия — операция по увеличению полового члена мужчины, посредством пересечения поддерживающей связки пениса. :D

Comment: @Sithell. Вы очень помогли :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Итоги:

Заинтересованных лиц не нашлось.
Печально, видимо слишком камерная игра.

---

Если кому-то хочется высказаться/указать_на_архитектурную_ошибку/вставь_своё, смело пишите, вдруг это поможет в будущем избежать подобного игнора?

Comment: Возможно, было бы хуже, если был один единственный участник. Замыкание "в кольцо" не помогло бы.

Comment: Ээх :-( Интроверты собрались тут.

Comment: Мне кажется проблема была в подарках, а именно в их формате. Лично я бы поучаствовал, но навскидку прикинул, что могли бы мне подарить в цифровом формате, ничего не пришло на ум, кроме как альбома на том же тунце.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, принтеров реальных предметов ещё нет (вероятно), поэтому только цифровые подарки. Многие отмечали что именно это их остановило.

Comment: @Other ну вот, значит в этом и был основной фейл данного мероприятия.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, могли бы пофиксить и предложить pull request :) Open-source же.

Comment: Слишком сложная схема - лень было разбираться в правилах и условиях.