# Традиции Stack Overflow на русском. Празднование дня знаний

Tags: обсуждение

Продолжим [тему традиций](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4682/213987).

Подумал я, что можно ввести новую традицию: праздновать на сайте [день знаний](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9).

У меня есть одно конкретное предложение, которое родилось глядя на то, как @NickVolynkin организует конкурсы на интересных вопросах, чтобы привлечь к ним внимание.

У нас есть много типовых закрывашек на темы отладки! Мы можем дружно организовывать каждый год синхронное поднятие этих вопросов на конкурсные страницы к первому сентября и организовывать таким образом целую неделю знаний.

Вот из того, что у нас уже понаписано:

- [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/213987)
- [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701409/213987)
- [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/213987)
- [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/213987)
- [Не работает css-класс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/714832/213987)
- [Для чего нужны свойства?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/197067/213987)

По-моему, идея вполне годная, можно к следующему году найти и поднять большое количество "школьных" вопросов.

Как вам?

Comment: Не хватает вопроса про C/C++. Многие студенты учатся именно на этих языках. Ну и есть Pascal школьный, но мне он кажется менее приоритетным.

Comment: *У нас есть много типовых закрывашек на темы отладки!* О чем это? Распишите понятнее. Ну и, допустим, инициативу поддержат голосами, что дальше? Кто будет спонсором, на каких вопросах, почему именно на них? Мало кто готов жертвовать своей репой для каких-то ленивых школьников. Всё это напоминает мне раздутого [тайного Санту](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4153/176217) с нулевым выхлопом. Да и первое апреля дальше обсуждений не прошло. Единственный профит - привлечение внимания к Мете :)

Comment: Не хватает вопроса про SVG, В свое время, я потратил очень много времени, чтобы разобраться с фундаментальными понятиями svg. Всё казалось так запутанно и непредсказуемо. Вот статья по фундаментальным основам SVG  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615562/28748

Comment: По отладке в Python тоже не хватает вопроса. Может займусь, но не факт.

Answer (score 8):

Несколько идей:

- Лучше не упоминать слова «день знаний», у школьников и студентов может быть к нему... некоторая неприязнь и протест.
- Я почему-то думаю, что конкурсную вкладку чаще открывают опытные участники в поисках чего-нибудь интересного, чем студенты, которым срочно нужно найти ответ. Я сам ее не открываю, когда ищу какое-то решение по работе — там его почти наверняка нет.
- Можно сделать вопрос-оглавление на Мете и его отмечать [важное](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5), чтобы ссылка была видна всем и на каждой странице.

---

По поводу конкурсов: привлечь внимание в течение конкурсной недели — не основная моя цель. План такой:

1. Благодаря конкурсу к вопросу и ответам привлекается внимание опытных участников, которые:

   - проверяют ответы на корректность, исправляют ошибки, дополняют;
   - плюсуют вопрос и ответы.
2. Заплюсованный вопрос навсегда остается в топе по своей метке, а то и в общем топе вопросов. Теперь он всегда будет получать больше просмотров, в том числе от новичков, которые:

   - просто любопытствуют, что там в лучших вопросах всех времён и народов;
   - интересуются лучшими вопросами по своей метке.
3. Новички читают хорошие вопросы и ответы. Миссия выполнена.

Answer (score 2):

Вопросы по отладке интересны, но конкурсы предполагают получение новых ответов, так что не очень подходят на эту роль. Предлагаю попривлекать к ним внимание какими-то другими способами.

Comment: Предлагаю совместить этот день с хэллоуином: вопросы с меткой [tag:мерлин-менсон] висят в блоке справа: "ТРУПНОЕ НА МЕТЕ", буквы на их страницах в форме чёртиков, ники в виде известных тематических персонажей вроде Дракулы или Джека, ответы (через `transform: rotate()`) крутят ведьмин хоровод вокруг вопроса, ...

Comment: @Skyrocker и на фоне звучит Вагнер.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, с завыванием оборотней и туманом на `WebGL`.

Comment: Может есть вариант на заглавную вывести статический блок? Или заглавная не кастомизируется никак?

Answer (score 2):

Есть два рода вопросов: вопросы, которые люди задают, и вопросы, которые им следовало бы задать.

Канонические вопросы типа «Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на языке X» ко второй категории относится. Внимание к ним привлекается, когда вы *явно ссылку на них* даёте. Например, в комментариях к хромающему Stack Overflow вопросу, чтобы помочь автору улучшить его (часто как [[mcve]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Конкурсы (featured questions) предназначены, чтобы привлечь внимание людей, которые  могут *ответить* на вопрос. Для канонических вопросов это слабо подходит, если вы хотите чтобы ответы на эти вопросы прочли люди, которым они могут помочь.

Нравится идея празднования. К примеру, в честь дня программиста 13 сентября 2017 года:

```py
>>> from datetime import *
>>> datetime(2017, 1, 1) + timedelta(0b1111_1111)
datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 13, 0, 0)
```

можно Debug-лотерею разыграть в течении недели/до конца сентября: чтобы получить билет, нужно найти опубликованный Stack Overflow вопрос, который можно улучшить, используя приёмы, описанные в ответах к каноническому вопросу по отладке, для выбранного языка, и оставить комментарий, помещая ссылку на канонический вопрос с явным указанием какой шаг может помочь автору вопроса его улучшить: сузить до конкретной проблемы, создать минимальный пример кода, который проблему показывает, явно указать буквальные примеры ввода/вывода, версии ПО, итд.

Публикуя ссылки на эти комментарии в объявлении лотереи на Мете, участник получает билет, если на момент подсчёта результатов (к примеру, день учителя) исходный вопрос получил одобренный ответ (в качестве индикации, что помогла ссылка). Два вопроса с одобренными ответами — два билета, три вопроса — три билета, итд. Чем больше билетов, тем больше шансов на победу.

Достаточно, если Мета-обсуждение с лотереей будет висеть в обсуждаемом (на основном сайте справа). При официальном статусе можно в [важное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5) добавить и/или победителям подарить различные [сувениры от Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/879/23044).

Даже без официального статуса, если вам нравится идея, то опубликуйте объявление о лотерее на Мета с произвольными изменениями на ваше усмотрение и желающие могут это использовать как повод обновить/создать новые канонические вопросы/ответы по отладке и донести ссылки на эти вопросам людям, которые в них больше всего нуждаются (большинство авторов новых вопросов на Stack Overflow).

С накопленным опытом, через год можно будет повторить.